# global search and replace on all lines that don't begin with a backslash

Tags: regular-expression, search, replace

I'm trying to globally enclose in `{}`'s all instances of `+,-,=` that aren't already so enclosed. But I don't want to do this for lines that are latex commands.   Since my latex commands are all on separate lines, and all begin with `\`, possibly preceded by `tab`s or `spaces`, my idea is to do the search and replace on any line *except* ones whose first non-whitespace character is  `\`     Here's a simple example:

```
\parindent=0 pt
    \parskip=12 pt 
$=$
${=}$
```

My search and replace should operate only on the third line.      From what I've read in this forum, the following *should* work at least for lines that begin with `\`, but it doesn't work even for this limited class, so I must be doing something wrong.

```
:g/^([^\\].*[^\{]=[^\}])/s/=/{=}/g
```

Could somebody please explain what I'm missing?    And of course,

As a bonus, if you could explain how I would do the enclosures for `+,-, and =` all in the one command, as opposed to three separate commands that would be most helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your global regex is a bit too complex for this, I think. I would use

```
vglobal/^\s*\\\|{[-+=]}/ ...
```

to match all the lines not starting with optional whitespace followed by a `\` and not containing one of the symbols already in braces. (The « backslash hell » is a necessary without `\v`, and even then you need `\\` for the actual backslash.)

Then, you can use a backreference to do the rest of the substitution (replaces the ellipsis above):

```
substitute/[-+=]/{&}/ge
```

Some finer points:

- `-` must come at the beginning or end of the character class because otherwise it builds a range.
- I used the `/e` flag because we are no loner guaranteed to have a match in the line (this is the price of simplifying the global match).

Comment: OP also included a fourth line where the `=` is already wrapped `{=}` and mentioned "only third line"... So maybe add some extra matches there? (Yeah this is getting complicated again, especially if you consider matches at the end of the line.)

Comment: Rats yeah. I think I’ll handle in the vglobal @filbranden

Comment: Also possible would be `s/{\?\([-+=]\)}\?/{\1}/ge`, which always substitutes but if one is already wrapped it will replace the curly braces too (effectively replacing it with itself.) This one also has a corner case that will replace `{=something}` with `{=}something}`, so yeah it's pretty hard to find a foolproof way to do this replacement.

Comment: Your current answer also uses `\1` without an actual capture group... Might as well just use `&` directly (like you suggested later.)

Comment: That's very elegant indeed, thank you both very much.     Two questions, one easy one hard:     1) what role does the \|  play?   2) Of course, the command is going to skip lines that have, for example, `{-} +`.      One very kludgy way around this would be to first replace all occurrences of {[-+=]} with their unbraced versions using something like `:g/{\([-+=]\)}/s// \1 /g` and *then* run something like `vg/^\s*\\/s/[-+=]/{&}/g` that will pick up all instances of unbraced +-=.     Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: @LeoSimon the backslash escapes the pipe, which is a regex « or »—with default magic settings, you write `\|` in vim (where you might just write `|` in other languages). As for 2, thats a fair point; you could build a smarter substitute: `:vg/^\s*/s/[^{][-+=][^}]/{&}/ge`

Comment: Thanks @dbenknoble, for some reason your proposal is giving me this response `Pattern found in every line: ^\s*` does that make sense to you?

Comment: @LeoSimon I suppose its because all lines start with zero or more spaces—I forgot the `\\` in the vg pattern!!